# Не отображаются встроенные директивы Vue "v-"

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Подключил библиотеку Vue, но не могу прописать встроенные директивы "v-", они просто не отображаются в качестве встроенных

Грубо говоря

```
<div class='root'>
  {{message}}
  <input type='text' v-model='message'/>
</div>
```

директива "v-model" никак не обрабатывается

UPD. Проблема была в очередности подключения библиотек. Суть в том, что на момент выполнения скрипта библиотеки не подключались. Проблема решена

Answer (score 1):

О какой обработке вы спрашиваете?
Посмотрите для вас создал [пример](https://codepen.io/osmaav/pen/ExgpxaN)

```js
const App = {
  data: () => ({
    title: 'Основы Vue 3',
    placeholder: 'введите текст',
    inputValue: ''
  }),
  watch: {
    inputValue(value) {
      this.inputValue = value
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  background: #1e2021;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(rgba(30, 32, 33, 0.2), 
    rgb(30, 42, 53)), 
    url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552910996-e666ad64695c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom center;
}

#app {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Inter, Roboto, Oxygen, Fira Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.root {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 700px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

hr {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1.45;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.form-control {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.form-control input {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <title>Основы Vue </title>
  <style>
    [v-cloak] {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  <main id="app">
    <div class="root" v-cloak>
      <h1 style="text-align: center" 
          v-text="title">
      </h1>
      <div class="form-control">
        <input type="text" 
               v-model="inputValue" 
               :placeholder =  placeholder
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Вы ввели: {{ inputValue }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```